# 7zip in bash script: create encrypted archive, but specify password in file instead of command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, encryption, passwords, 7-zip

I can compress a 7zip archive with encryption like this:

```
7z a -pSECRET example.7z *.doc
```

But in this case I specify the password (`SECRET`) literally on the command line.

Is it also possible to specify a *filename* that contains the password? E.g. something like this:

```
7z a -p@passwordfile.txt example.7z *.doc
```

Except this doesn't work, in this case it will encrypt the archive literally using the password '@passwordfile.txt'.

Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: `-p"$(cat passwordfile.txt)"`, or maybe `(read secret < passwordfile.txt; 7z a -p"$secret" example.7z *.doc)`

Comment: @TomYan Thanks but that way the password still becomes literally included in the actual command line. If I'd do `ps -aux | grep 7z` in another shell while it's encrypting, it shows the password there. And possibly it's even being logged in `~/.bash_history`.

I was hoping for a possibility of 7z itself to specify a password in a file, but maybe such a feature simply isn't there?

Comment: @RocketNuts For a couple other potential ways/ideas https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hiding-passwords-in-bash-scirpts-4175576896/page2.html and https://www.howtogeek.com/734838/how-to-use-encrypted-passwords-in-bash-scripts/

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/a/1358942/340330